# org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException Can't load the XML resource iText PDF

Tags: struts2, itext

We have a struts 2 application where we have implemented feature to download / extract contents of a web page/ JSP to PDF. We are using iText for the same.
That functionality works fine when I am running the application in my local, Dev environment and works fine on individual Test server i.e. when I am accessing
the application using individual server URLs. Recently we have migrated the app to Test and we have setup domain URL. After migrating to domain URL, 
download/ extract PDF feature is throwing error. Given below is the Code & stack trace from server.log. 
(FYI...I am running the app on JBoss 5 server.)

I urgently need to resolve this problem, request someone please assist me on this.

Code: This is the function called inside my action class - DownloadPriceSheetAction.

```
private String generatePDF(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(ApplicationConstants.PRICE_SHEET,
            ApplicationConstants.PDF);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

    StringBuilder stringURLBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringURLBuilder.append(request.getScheme());
    stringURLBuilder.append(ApplicationConstants.PDF_COLLEN);
    stringURLBuilder.append(ApplicationConstants.PDF_DOUBLE_SLASH);
    stringURLBuilder.append(request.getServerName());
    stringURLBuilder.append(ApplicationConstants.PDF_COLLEN);
    stringURLBuilder.append(request.getServerPort());
    stringURLBuilder.append(request.getContextPath());
    stringURLBuilder.append(ApplicationConstants.PDF_SLASH);
    stringURLBuilder.append(ApplicationConstants.PDF_ACTION);
    stringURLBuilder.append(getGenerateURL());

    logger.debug("\n URL = " + stringURLBuilder.toString() + "\n");

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(stringURLBuilder.toString());
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
    os.close();
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
    return ApplicationConstants.PDF;
}
```

Comment: You didn't include the stack trace.

Comment: org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:191)
 org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:71)
 org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent.getXMLResource(NaiveUserAgent.java:211)
 org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.loadDocument(ITextRenderer.java:134)
 org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:138)
 com.customer.catalogui.actions.DownloadPriceSheetAction

Comment: This is all I am able to attach, could you please help !!

Comment: Edit your question and place the stack trace in there. Then you'll have plenty of room for it.

Comment: Also include the constants with which you're building your path, or the actual path.